# Regex (PHP) - How to match as many times as possible with multiple lines

Tags: regex

String Block:

```
abc
de
xxx
a
bcd
e
```

How do I match ***abcde*** twice? The line break can happen in any places.

```
/a.*e/s  matches whole block once.
```

[Regex Fiddle here.](https://regex101.com/r/pQ4eL1/1)

Comment: which flavor of regex are you using. what don't you want to match

Comment: It is for PCRE (PHP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the greediness operator ?

```
a.*?e
```

instead of

```
a.*e
```

What you are using tries to give you maximum possible match, which is done in the first match of the whole string, that is why you are getting only one match.

i tried it on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use str_replace to remove the breaks (\r\n).

```
$string= str_replace("\r\n","",$stringblock);
```

Then you can check if $string matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
a\s*b\s*c\s*d\s*e
```

Can be done using this but not extendable.see demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/15

Comment: Thanks, but my string is way more letters than abcde.